# How can I update an array using useState, with as many numbers as the ones I pass to the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an image slider that gives you n new images every time you click. I am struggling to understand how to make this piece of code dynamic so that it updates the array that takes care of the indexes as many times as the number I pass to the function (in this case 3)

```
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setIndex((prevIndex) => [
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 1,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 2,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 3,
    ]);
  };
```

This is the entire code

```
function useImageSlider(range: number = 3, length: number, steps: number = 1) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number[]>(Array.from(Array(range).keys()));

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setIndex((prevIndex) => [
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] - 1,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] - 2,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] - 3,
    ]);
  };
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    index[index.length - 1] + steps + 1 >= length &&
      setIndex((prevState) => [...prevState, -1]);
    setIndex((prevIndex) => [
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 1,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 2,
      prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + 3,
    ]);
  };
  return { length, steps, handleIncrement, handleDecrement, index };
}
export default useImageSlider;
```

Comment: can you add more related code for the slider?

Comment: _"takes care of the indexes"_: what does this mean? Can you not just add new images refs to the array?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I just edited the post

Comment: @Andy I fetch the data from an endpoint, and then display n images at the time, 3 in this case, and then map them like image[index]. I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @illyria, what is length? is it the number of all the images you have?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera It is, it seems like brabade's answer below works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleIncrement = (range) => {
setIndex((prevIndex) => [...Array(range).keys()].map(arrIndex =>
  prevIndex[prevIndex.length - 1] + arrIndex + 1));
};
```